# Does SSO is implementable with the exoPlatform Community edition?

Tags: single-sign-on, compatibility

I use the community edition of exoPlatform 4.3 that I retrieve in a Docker image.

I implemented the LDAP functionality with exo.
It works perfectly and now I'm trying to implement SSO with openAM. For LDAP, it was clear that there was no need to build the exo project with Maven, which I don't think I can do with the Docker exo community version.

I can't find out if it's possible to do the same with the SSO feature. 
Could someone please help me?